# mathematical expression evaluator with parameter

Tags: c++

I made an expression evaluator and I want to add to it a parameter... say I can calculate: (1+1)*13 = 26 but what (1+1)*x would look like if x takes values in a defined interval.
This is my code:

```
int eval(int a, int b, char o)
{
    switch(o)
    {
        case '+': return a + b;
        case '-': return a - b;
        case '*': return a * b;
        case '/': return a / b;
    }
}

int expr(int lev)
{
    int x, y;
    if(lev == LMax)
        if(*p == '(')
            ++p, x = expr(0), ++p;
        else
        {
            for(x = 0; *p >= '0' && *p <= '9'; ++p)
                x = x * 10 + *p - '0';
        }
    else
    {
        for(x = expr(lev + 1); strchr(op[lev], *p); x = y)
            y = eval(x, expr(lev + 1), *p++);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: How do I add the parameter so my code will still understand the expression

Comment: Which parameter? What have you tried? Where are you having problems? If your question is "please write an expression evaluator for me" you probably won't have much luck here.

Comment: @Rook dude, my evaluator works. All I am asking is how do I make it understand that "x" in the expression... Do I have to do the same expression that many times my x takes values from?

Comment: In general you would need to evaluate the expression at several _x_ values across the defined interval in order to get and idea of the "shape" of the plot of the _y_ values.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yeah, i figured that out but how do I do that?

Comment: Well, _expr_ would need to recognize an 'x' in the expression, and know what value to substitute for it; maybe the _x_ value could be an argument to _expr_.  You'd have to set up a loop to call _expr_ with a series of _x_ values in the desired interval.  You'd have to give the user a way to specify the interval and possibly the step value between successive _x_ values.